# Hyperledger Fabric: peer chaincode instantiate error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

> Error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker
>   build: Error returned from build: 1 "can't load package: package
>   ../../bin/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/chaincode/marbles: open
>   /bin/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/chaincode/marbles: no such file or
>   directory.

I see it is looking for a relative directory. relative to what? chaincode install was fine. If the chaincode is installed, why can it not be found for instantiate? 1 peer. 1 solo orderer. channel joined fine.

Comment: it looks like it cannot compile the chaincode because it needs a dependent package that is not installed in the container.

Comment: what was the process or command here was used, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chaincode install doesn't mean you have correctly mapped your chaincode path,

```
peer chaincode install -p {path} -n {} -v {}
```

Chaincode instantiate builds and instantiate your chaincode.

```
peer chaincode instantiate -n {} -v {} -c {} -C {}
```

- In docker compose file double check the volumes/chaincode mapping of
  the cli.
- Use actual path when installing chaincode.

Comment: I installed from the directory the chaincode is in.  i.e. -p ./  Attempting to reinstall yields the correct error of already exists. Chaincode.0 file exists in /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes. Not using docker. I know it said OK on install and I believe it said 0 block received or something like that.

Comment: Ah. So the chaincode path must be something like github.com/hyperledger/fabric/chaincode/ccname which is relative to gopath somehow. Full path is /usr/local/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/chaincode/ccname. $GOPATH is /usr/local/go/bin. $GOROOT is /usr/local/go. So fabric expects chaincode in $GOROOT/src/? Seems odd but works. thx

Comment: @MohamedYoussef sorry for hijacking the question in advance. I'm using the NodeJS SDK and I'm getting an ok on install and a fail on instantiate. Could you have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963477/hyperledger-fabric-cant-find-go-files-when-building-chaincode?

Answer (score 2):

There's a "hidden" expectation in the path mapping. It expects there to be a /src directory under gopath that caused me some trouble until I figured it out.

Here's my solution fwiw:

In your compose yaml for the peer you would set the env variable :

`- GOPATH=/opt/gopath`

Then in the CLI you can install and instantiate thus:

```
SIGNED_CHAINCODE_LOCATION=/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/<cc_dir>/<signed_cc>.out

peer chaincode install /${SIGNED_CHAINCODE_LOCATION}
```

And instantiate as normal. 
Just use the directory instead of the .out file if you don't need to package and sign.

In my case I added a working dir in the peer that set the chain code to a relative directory to my base blockchain directory: `- ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/` and dumped the go folder into there.