# Hyperledger Fabric can't find go files when building chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem**
I'm getting the following error on a fabric-peer: `Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "can't load package: package chaincodes/simple: no buildable Go source files in /chaincode/input/src/chaincodes/simple`.

**Context**
I'm trying to instantiate a chaincode package after having successfully installed it.
Both the install and instantiate proposals are created by the Fabric NodeJS SDK (fabric-client).

**Steps leading up to the problem**

- Package a go file using the fabric-client (succeeds)
- Create an install proposal and send it to the peer (succeeds
- Create and instantiate proposal and send it to the peer (fails with above error-message)

**Steps taken to solve the problem**
I tried to assert how the chaincode container create process works by reading the code.
What I got from it was the following:
 - The chaincode is build using the fabric-ccenv image
 - It loads a .tar as an Inputstream  (The package?)

I tried adding the files to the go-path but I still couldn't get it to work.

**What I want to know**
- Where does the chaincode building process expect these files to be?
- Why do I need to provide the files when I've previously sent a package of chaincode inside an InstallRequest?

**Further information**
I'm also getting an error about an MSP being unknown. Something along the lines of: `Error: MSP Org1MSP is unkown`. This happens during deserialization of the proposal.
Which is weird because I'm 100% that MSP exists. What I'm not certain about is whether I need to add anchor peers to the channel I'm installing and instantiating the chaincode on in order for the MSP to be found.
I thought that happens during channel creation.

**Versions**
This happens in the following versions:
- 1.0.0
- 1.0.6

Please do not suggest I try version 1.1 because I cannot upgrade easily.

Please advise.

Comment: Hi, i also received that same error. i tried with Go Chaincode, it worked ok but when i started instantiating Java chaincode, it had problem like you. could you tell me the solution? I checked my MSP Dir is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above was caused by an actual `unknown` MSP.

Double check the profile/profiles in `configtx.yaml` used for creating the channel and the genesis block for orderers. I had a mismatch between those.

I read a related issue [[FAB-7952](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-7952)] in Fabric's issue manager and it made me think something else was going on, instead of an actual unknown MSP.