# How do I find chain code location in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am following through the fabric-samples - balance-transfer project on [GitHub](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/balance-transfer/typescript)

I am able to walk through setting up the chain code and query the transaction with their provided example chain code in node.

I want to include my own custom chain code in the github.com/ directory, I was able to install the chain code by providing the curl command

```sh
curl -s -X POST \
>   http://localhost:4000/chaincodes \
>   -H "authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NTkxNTU3NzIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiSmltIiwib3JnTmFtZSI6Im9yZzEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTkxMTk3NzJ9.52cwFysSFcADjvGUtri-hBSERhj2lz3MiGNk8yvBT-Q" \
>   -H "content-type: application/json" \
>   -d '{
> "peers": ["peer1","peer2"],
> "chaincodeName":"mycc",
> "chaincodePath":"github.com/car-trade",
> "chaincodeVersion":"v0"
> }'
```

I was able to get the message 
***Successfully Installed chaincode on organization org1***

But when I instantiated the chain code using the curl command

```sh
curl -s -X POST \
>   http://localhost:4000/channels/mychannel/chaincodes \
>   -H "authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NTkxNTU3NzIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiSmltIiwib3JnTmFtZSI6Im9yZzEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTkxMTk3NzJ9.52cwFysSFcADjvGUtri-hBSERhj2lz3MiGNk8yvBT-Q" \
>   -H "content-type: application/json" \
>   -d '{
> "chaincodeName":"mycc",
> "chaincodeVersion":"v0",
> "args":["a","100","b","200"]
> }'
```

I got an error message 
***Failed to send instantiate Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting...***

When I tried to log the response that I`m getting in the chain code API in the file [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/typescript/lib/channel.ts).

```js
const results = await channel.sendInstantiateProposal(request);
proposalResponses.forEach((pr: ProposalResponse) => {
    console.log(pr);
}
```

I got the message,

```
{ Error: error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "can't load package: package github.com/car-trade: cannot find package "github.com/car-trade" in any of:
        /opt/go/src/github.com/car-trade (from $GOROOT)
        /chaincode/input/src/github.com/car-trade (from $GOPATH)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/car-trade
"
    at self._endorserClient.processProposal (/home/raj/Documents/verifyV2/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/typescript/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:140:36)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/raj/Documents/verifyV2/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/typescript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1207:9)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/raj/Documents/verifyV2/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/typescript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/raj/Documents/verifyV2/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/typescript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
    at callback (/home/raj/Documents/verifyV2/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/typescript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24)
  status: 500,
  payload: <Buffer >,
  peer: 
   { url: 'grpcs://localhost:7056',
     name: 'peer2',
     options: 
      { 'grpc.max_receive_message_length': -1,
        'grpc.max_send_message_length': -1,
        'grpc.keepalive_time_ms': 120000,
        'grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms': 120000,
        'grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms': 20000,
        'grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data': 0,
        'grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls': 1,
        'grpc.ssl_target_name_override': 'peer1.org1.example.com',
        'grpc.default_authority': 'peer1.org1.example.com' } },
  isProposalResponse: true }
```

I went inside the peer container and looked into the github.com directory which need to have the chain code both the example_cc as well as my custom chain code. But I was not able to find neither.

I would like to know where the chaincode reside, both the example chaincode and the custom chaincode.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811019/hyperledger-fabric-peer-chaincode-instantiate-error

Comment: If chain code is not located inside the docker, maybe you should check your docker configuration file. Make sure your chaincode folder is mounted.